# Why am I getting an error of "type arguments...do not conform to trait..." compiler error?

Tags: scala, generics, type-parameter, type-bounds

I have been stuck on a Scala (2.11.7) compiler error in IntelliJ (14.1.5) now for several hours. I have Googled, wracked my brain and experimented with a ton of variations but cannot seem to get around it.

I have taken the code context and clipped it down as small as I could (including clipping out any external library dependencies) to capture the domain I have been using to try and narrow down the issue. I thought I was using pretty straightforward idiomatic Scala; case objects, traits with type parameters, etc.

The fourth from the last line starting with `abstract case class CoordinateRadian` is the one generating this Scala compiler error:

> Error:(128, 129) type arguments
>   [Test.this.CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type,Test.this.LongitudeRadian,Test.this.LatitudeRadian]
>   do not conform to trait Coordinate's type parameter bounds [U <:
>   Test.this.Angle.UnitBase.Member,+O <: Test.this.Longitude[U],+A <:
>   Test.this.Latitude[U]]   abstract case class CoordinateRadian
>   private[CoordinateRadian] (longitude: LongitudeRadian, latitude:
>   LatitudeRadian) extends Coordinate[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type,
>   LongitudeRadian, LatitudeRadian] {

Here's the code with the compiler error:

```
package org.public_domain

class Test {
  object Angle {
    object UnitBase {
      trait Member
      case object RADIAN extends Member
      case object DEGREE extends Member
    }
    trait UnitBase[U <: Angle.UnitBase.Member] {
      def unitBase: U
    }

    object ZeroBase {
      trait Member
      case object LEFT extends Member
      case object MIDDLE extends Member
    }
    trait ZeroBase[U <: Angle.UnitBase.Member, Z <: Angle.ZeroBase.Member] extends Angle.UnitBase[U] {
      def zeroBase: Z
    }
  }
  trait Angle[U <: Angle.UnitBase.Member, Z <: Angle.ZeroBase.Member] extends Angle.ZeroBase[U, Z] {
    def theta: Double
  }

  trait Angle__ObjectBase {
    def basesAsTuple: (Angle.UnitBase.Member, Angle.ZeroBase.Member)
  }

  object AngleRadianMiddle extends ((Double) => AngleRadianMiddle) with Angle__ObjectBase {
    val basesAsTuple: (Angle.UnitBase.Member, Angle.ZeroBase.Member) =
      (Angle.UnitBase.RADIAN, Angle.ZeroBase.MIDDLE)

    def apply(theta: Double): AngleRadianMiddle =
      new AngleRadianMiddle(theta) {
        def unitBase =
          basesAsTuple._1

        def zeroBase =
          basesAsTuple._2

        private def readResolve(): Object =
          AngleRadianMiddle(theta)

        def copy(thetaNew: Double = theta): AngleRadianMiddle =
          AngleRadianMiddle(thetaNew)
      }
  }
  abstract case class AngleRadianMiddle private[AngleRadianMiddle] (theta: Double) extends Angle[AngleRadianMiddle.basesAsTuple._1.type, AngleRadianMiddle.basesAsTuple._2.type] {
    def copy(thetaNew: Double = theta): AngleRadianMiddle
  }

  trait Itude[U <: Angle.UnitBase.Member] extends Angle[U, Angle.ZeroBase.MIDDLE.type] {
    val zeroBase =
      Angle.ZeroBase.MIDDLE
  }

  sealed trait Longitude[U <: Angle.UnitBase.Member] extends Itude[U]
  sealed trait Latitude[U <: Angle.UnitBase.Member] extends Itude[U]

  object LongitudeRadian extends ((Double) => LongitudeRadian) {
    val basesAsTuple: (Angle.UnitBase.Member, Angle.ZeroBase.Member) =
      (Angle.UnitBase.RADIAN, Angle.ZeroBase.MIDDLE)

    def apply(theta: Double): LongitudeRadian =
      new LongitudeRadian(theta) {
        def unitBase =
          basesAsTuple._1

        private def readResolve(): Object =
          LongitudeRadian(theta)

        def copy(thetaNew: Double = theta): LongitudeRadian =
          LongitudeRadian(thetaNew)
      }
  }
  abstract case class LongitudeRadian(theta: Double) extends Longitude[LongitudeRadian.basesAsTuple._1.type] {
    def copy(thetaNew: Double = theta): LongitudeRadian
  }

  object LatitudeRadian extends ((Double) => LatitudeRadian) {
    val basesAsTuple: (Angle.UnitBase.Member, Angle.ZeroBase.Member) =
      (Angle.UnitBase.RADIAN, Angle.ZeroBase.MIDDLE)

    def apply(theta: Double): LatitudeRadian =
      new LatitudeRadian(theta) {
        def unitBase =
          basesAsTuple._1

        private def readResolve(): Object =
          LatitudeRadian(theta)

        def copy(thetaNew: Double = theta): LatitudeRadian =
          LatitudeRadian(thetaNew)
      }
  }
  abstract case class LatitudeRadian(theta: Double) extends Latitude[LatitudeRadian.basesAsTuple._1.type] {
    def copy(thetaNew: Double = theta): LatitudeRadian
  }

  trait Coordinate[U <: Angle.UnitBase.Member, +O <: Longitude[U], +A <: Latitude[U]] {
    def longitude: O
    def latitude: A

    val x: O =
      longitude
    val y: A =
      latitude
  }

  object CoordinateRadian extends ((LongitudeRadian, LatitudeRadian) => CoordinateRadian) {
    val unitBase: Angle.UnitBase.Member =
      Angle.UnitBase.RADIAN

    def apply(longitude: LongitudeRadian, latitude: LatitudeRadian): CoordinateRadian =
      new CoordinateRadian(longitude, latitude) {
        private def readResolve(): Object =
          CoordinateRadian(longitude, latitude)

        def copy(longitudeNew: LongitudeRadian = longitude, latitudeNew: LatitudeRadian = latitude): CoordinateRadian =
          CoordinateRadian(longitudeNew, latitudeNew)
      }
  }
  //abstract case class CoordinateRadian private[CoordinateRadian] (longitude: LongitudeRadian, latitude: LatitudeRadian) extends Coordinate[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type, Longitude[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type], Latitude[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type]] {
  abstract case class CoordinateRadian private[CoordinateRadian] (longitude: LongitudeRadian, latitude: LatitudeRadian) extends Coordinate[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type, LongitudeRadian, LatitudeRadian] {
    def copy(longitudeNew: LongitudeRadian = longitude, latitudeNew: LatitudeRadian = latitude): CoordinateRadian
  }
}
```

You will notice the fifth line from the end of the file is a commented out line (and very similar to the fourth line from the end of the file). If you uncomment the fifth from the end line and then comment out the fourth from the end line and compile the code ("Build All" in IntelliJ), two errors will be emitted:

> Error:(125, 67) overriding method longitude in trait Coordinate of
>   type => Test.this.Longitude[Test.this.CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type];
>   value longitude has incompatible type   abstract case class
>   CoordinateRadian private[CoordinateRadian] (longitude:
>   LongitudeRadian, latitude: LatitudeRadian) extends
>   Coordinate[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type,
>   Longitude[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type],
>   Latitude[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type]] {
>
> Error:(125, 95) overriding method latitude in trait Coordinate of type
>   => Test.this.Latitude[Test.this.CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type];  value latitude has incompatible type   abstract case class
>   CoordinateRadian private[CoordinateRadian] (longitude:
>   LongitudeRadian, latitude: LatitudeRadian) extends
>   Coordinate[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type,
>   Longitude[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type],
>   Latitude[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type]] {

I may have just worked on this too long and now have a jaundiced eye. I haven't thought of any new ways to approach this in over an hour. SO, any guidance on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by constraints on `Coordinate` you need to have `LongitudeRadian <: Longitude[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type]` (and similarly for latitude), which is wrong because `LatitudeRadian.basesAsTuple._1.type` isn't a subtype of `CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type` (the compiler knows only that `LatitudeRadian.basesAsTuple._1` is an `Angle.UnitBase.Member`). If you just remove type annotations from `basesAsTuple` and `unitBase`, the compiler [will infer the singleton types without problems](http://scastie.org/12484).

```
class Test {
  object Angle {
    object UnitBase {
      trait Member
      case object RADIAN extends Member
      case object DEGREE extends Member
    }
    trait UnitBase[U <: Angle.UnitBase.Member] {
      def unitBase: U
    }

    object ZeroBase {
      trait Member
      case object LEFT extends Member
      case object MIDDLE extends Member
    }
    trait ZeroBase[U <: Angle.UnitBase.Member, Z <: Angle.ZeroBase.Member] extends Angle.UnitBase[U] {
      def zeroBase: Z
    }
  }
  trait Angle[U <: Angle.UnitBase.Member, Z <: Angle.ZeroBase.Member] extends Angle.ZeroBase[U, Z] {
    def theta: Double
  }

  trait Angle__ObjectBase {
    def basesAsTuple: (Angle.UnitBase.Member, Angle.ZeroBase.Member)
  }

  object AngleRadianMiddle extends ((Double) => AngleRadianMiddle) with Angle__ObjectBase {
    val basesAsTuple =
      (Angle.UnitBase.RADIAN, Angle.ZeroBase.MIDDLE)

    def apply(theta: Double): AngleRadianMiddle =
      new AngleRadianMiddle(theta) {
        def unitBase =
          basesAsTuple._1

        def zeroBase =
          basesAsTuple._2

        private def readResolve(): Object =
          AngleRadianMiddle(theta)

        def copy(thetaNew: Double = theta): AngleRadianMiddle =
          AngleRadianMiddle(thetaNew)
      }
  }
  abstract case class AngleRadianMiddle private[AngleRadianMiddle] (theta: Double) extends Angle[AngleRadianMiddle.basesAsTuple._1.type, AngleRadianMiddle.basesAsTuple._2.type] {
    def copy(thetaNew: Double = theta): AngleRadianMiddle
  }

  trait Itude[U <: Angle.UnitBase.Member] extends Angle[U, Angle.ZeroBase.MIDDLE.type] {
    val zeroBase =
      Angle.ZeroBase.MIDDLE
  }

  sealed trait Longitude[U <: Angle.UnitBase.Member] extends Itude[U]
  sealed trait Latitude[U <: Angle.UnitBase.Member] extends Itude[U]

  object LongitudeRadian extends ((Double) => LongitudeRadian) {
    val basesAsTuple =
      (Angle.UnitBase.RADIAN, Angle.ZeroBase.MIDDLE)

    def apply(theta: Double): LongitudeRadian =
      new LongitudeRadian(theta) {
        def unitBase =
          basesAsTuple._1

        private def readResolve(): Object =
          LongitudeRadian(theta)

        def copy(thetaNew: Double = theta): LongitudeRadian =
          LongitudeRadian(thetaNew)
      }
  }
  abstract case class LongitudeRadian(theta: Double) extends Longitude[LongitudeRadian.basesAsTuple._1.type] {
    def copy(thetaNew: Double = theta): LongitudeRadian
  }

  object LatitudeRadian extends ((Double) => LatitudeRadian) {
    val basesAsTuple =
      (Angle.UnitBase.RADIAN, Angle.ZeroBase.MIDDLE)

    def apply(theta: Double): LatitudeRadian =
      new LatitudeRadian(theta) {
        def unitBase =
          basesAsTuple._1

        private def readResolve(): Object =
          LatitudeRadian(theta)

        def copy(thetaNew: Double = theta): LatitudeRadian =
          LatitudeRadian(thetaNew)
      }
  }
  abstract case class LatitudeRadian(theta: Double) extends Latitude[LatitudeRadian.basesAsTuple._1.type] {
    def copy(thetaNew: Double = theta): LatitudeRadian
  }

  trait Coordinate[U <: Angle.UnitBase.Member, +O <: Longitude[U], +A <: Latitude[U]] {
    def longitude: O
    def latitude: A

    val x: O =
      longitude
    val y: A =
      latitude
  }

  object CoordinateRadian extends ((LongitudeRadian, LatitudeRadian) => CoordinateRadian) {
    val unitBase =
      Angle.UnitBase.RADIAN

    def apply(longitude: LongitudeRadian, latitude: LatitudeRadian): CoordinateRadian =
      new CoordinateRadian(longitude, latitude) {
        private def readResolve(): Object =
          CoordinateRadian(longitude, latitude)

        def copy(longitudeNew: LongitudeRadian = longitude, latitudeNew: LatitudeRadian = latitude): CoordinateRadian =
          CoordinateRadian(longitudeNew, latitudeNew)
      }
  }
  //abstract case class CoordinateRadian private[CoordinateRadian] (longitude: LongitudeRadian, latitude: LatitudeRadian) extends Coordinate[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type, Longitude[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type], Latitude[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type]] {

  abstract case class CoordinateRadian private[CoordinateRadian] (longitude: LongitudeRadian, latitude: LatitudeRadian) extends Coordinate[CoordinateRadian.unitBase.type, LongitudeRadian, LatitudeRadian] {
    def copy(longitudeNew: LongitudeRadian = longitude, latitudeNew: LatitudeRadian = latitude): CoordinateRadian
  }
}
```

But to be honest, this looks like overuse of singleton types to me. I don't see why you need `unitBase` and `basesAsTuple` at all. I'd prefer to write

```
abstract case class LongitudeRadian(theta: Double) extends Longitude[RADIAN.type]

abstract case class CoordinateRadian private[CoordinateRadian] (longitude: LongitudeRadian, latitude: LatitudeRadian) extends Coordinate[RADIAN.type, LongitudeRadian, LatitudeRadian]
```

etc. Much less opportunity for being bitten by the compiler being unable to prove two objects are the same.

Comment: Awesome! Tysvm! I really appreciate your answer. Of course, it begs the next questions...why is my repeating EXACTLY THE SAME type information in those declarations (if identity is identity...) causing the compiler to become confused? I've run into so many compiler issues the other direction (incorrectly inferring types), I have favored over specifying types by default. It's quite frustrating to see now even over specifying (on an identity basis) can cause the compiler issues.

Comment: And how in the Hades did you figure your answer out? What made you think to go remove the over-specification of types for basesAsTuple and unitBase? I'm just trying to work through how I might be able to do the same for myself in the future. Do you have some extra tool you are using that surfaces more of what the compiler is doing and about which it is confused that lead you to those particular declarations? That's not a route I would have ever considered (given my identity assumption).

Comment: As I said, just looking at constraints for `Coordinate` and the type parameters of `CoordinateRadian` and `LatitudeRadian` made it clear. You aren't "repeating the same information": the compiler infers e.g. `val basesAsTuple: (Angle.UnitBase.RADIAN.type, Angle.ZeroBase.MIDDLE.type)` in `LatitudeRadian`, _not_ `val basesAsTuple: (Angle.UnitBase.Member, Angle.ZeroBase.Member)`. So it knows that `LatitudeRadian.basesAsTuple._1` is `Angle.UnitBase.RADIAN` and `LatitudeRadian.basesAsTuple._1.type` is the same as `Angle.UnitBase.RADIAN.type` which is what the constraint requires.

Comment: So, is there an explicit way to add the type specifier to basesAsTuple and retain the inferred meaning? Or, is it require I leave off the type specifier as that is the only way the compiler can make the inference leap? I sure hope it is the former as the latter is a pretty nasty and annoying pitfall.

Comment: Yes, and it's given in the above comment: `val basesAsTuple: (Angle.UnitBase.RADIAN.type, Angle.ZeroBase.MIDDLE.type)`.

Comment: Hmm. That implies that everywhere I want to use a case object, I need to be aware of whether I am using it as just a value versus where I am using it just as a type. Or, to your point, if I leave off the specification entirely (except for the original specification in the parent trait), the compiler can make the value-to-type inference for me. There's still something off for me around this. I sure wish there was a more visual way to represent this so I can grok all of it and see the general principle I am likely missing.